# cannot run a java file in geany

Tags: java

When I try to run a java file from geany it shows that,

```
20:14:08: Cannot execute build command "cmd.exe /Q /C ^"C:\Program^ Files\Geany\libexec\geany\geany-run-helper^"^ ^"G:\Lahiru^"^ 0^ java^ ^"Example^"":

Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software. Check the Terminal setting in Preferences
```

What is the reason for this issue?

I attempted to reinstall the software twice, but the problem persisted. Additionally, I disabled the Avast software for one hour, yet the issue remained unresolved.

Comment: This doesn't look like the [right command](https://ericplayground.com/2015/06/07/how-to-configure-geany-to-run-java/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.